# What do the colors in a jump-path indicate?

Tags: endless-sky

In Endless Sky, you can create a jump-path from one system to another. What do the colors of the jump path represent (particularly yellow), how are they calculated, and are there colors *other* than green, yellow and red?

It seems that the colors indicate the range of your fleet (not just your flagship) based on the current fuel supply of each ship.

I've seen this vary a lot: paths with more than one yellow link, paths that are *only* yellow (one ship, 500 fuel), paths with no yellow links, etc.

To the best of my knowledge:

- **Green** indicates the maximum number of jumps you can take along that route without *any* ship refueling.
- **Yellow**??
- **Red** indicates jump paths that are beyond the yellow range?

Here's a screenshot with a fleet of 8 escorts (min fuel 400, max fuel 600)

[image: Screenshot of Jump Path]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

green = all ships can make it without refueling

yellow = some ships will require refueling

red = your ship will require refueling

This does not include ramscoops into the calculation so your range may actually be  greater than what is shown. This was pretty noticeable.

Also AI ships can jump regardless of whether or not they have fuel which includes your fleet. I took note of this when one of my ships had 0 fuel and made two consecutive jumps trying to reach me.

Answer (score 1):

The colors tell you how far you (and your fleet) can jump before needing to refuel. This helps when planning long trips to prevent you from ending up stranded, out of fuel, in an unfriendly system.

The yellow line represents how far YOUR ship can make it without refueling.

The red line represents areas you cannot make it to without refueling somewhere along the way.

If you have a fleet, you will also see a green line that represents how far your entire fleet can jump without refueling.

https://github.com/endless-sky/endless-sky/pull/171

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, green indicates that *all* of your ships can make that journey.  Orange-red means that none of your ships can make that journey. Yellow means that some of your ships can make that journey.